# Predicting and Plotting Survival Curve with the CoxPH

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am trying to predict and plot the (estimated) survival curve for a new observation in R. Using the "survival" library and the "lung" data set, I first fit a cox proportional hazards model to the data. Then, I tried to predict and plot the survival curve for a hypothetical new observation (I entered the details for this hypothetical new observation in the "list" command). However, this is not working.

I have attached my code below:

```
#load library
library(survival)
data(lung)

#create survival object
s <- with(lung,Surv(time,status))

#create model
modelA  <- coxph(s ~ as.factor(sex)+age+ph.ecog+wt.loss+ph.karno,data=lung, model=TRUE)
summary(modelA)

#plot
plot(survfit(modelA), ylab="Probability of Survival",
     xlab="Time", col=c("red", "black", "black"))

#predict for a hypothetical NEW observation (here is where the error is)
lines(predict(modelA, newdata=list(sex=1, 
                                  age = 56, 
                                  ph.ecog = 1, 
                                  ph.karno = 50,
                                  wt.loss = 11),
               type="quantile",
               p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),
       seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),
       col="blue")
## Error in match.arg(type) : 
##  'arg' should be one of “lp”, “risk”, “expected”, “terms”, “survival”
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is what the `survfit` function is for. In your example, you plot the `survfit` for the model, but you can feed a `newdata` argument into this function and it will produce the estimated survival for these data.

If we reproduce your example:

```r
library(survival)

s <- with(lung, Surv(time, status))

modelA  <- coxph(s ~ as.factor(sex) + age + ph.ecog + wt.loss + ph.karno,
                 data = lung, model = TRUE)

plot(survfit(modelA), ylab = "Probability of Survival",
     xlab = "Time", col = c("red", "black", "black"))
```

[image]

Then we can create a survival curve given your specified covariates like this:

```r
est <- survfit(modelA, newdata = data.frame(sex      = 1,
                                            age      = 56,
                                            ph.ecog  = 1, 
                                            ph.karno = 50,
                                            wt.loss  = 11))
```

Now `est` is an S3 object with members that include `time` and `survival`, so we can plot a blue line tracking the estimated survival of individuals with the given covariates like this:

```r
lines(est$time, est$surv, col = 'blue', type = 's')
```

[image]

Or plot it on its own with a 95% confidence interval:

```r
plot(est, ylab = "Probability of Survival",
     xlab = "Time", col = c("red", "black", "black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

See the description of the `predict()` function (you can open it in R help by running `?predict.coxph`, or [here for example](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/3.2-3/topics/predict.coxph)):

> **type** - the type of predicted value. Choices are the linear predictor
> (`"lp"`), the risk score exp(lp) (`"risk"`), the expected number of events
> given the covariates and follow-up time (`"expected"`), and the terms of
> the linear predictor (`"terms"`). The survival probability for a subject
> is equal to exp(-expected).

You can see that your `type="quantile"` does not match expected input. If you call `predict()` without the `type` argument, in your case it will default to using `lp` (linear predictor).
When you call `predict()` function for your object `modelA`, it determines that it is of `coxph` class, so the `predict.coxph()` function is applied. The arguments like `type="quantile"` and `p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)` are not acceptable for `predict.coxph()` (`p` is ignored, `type` raises error). They are used in another function, `predict.survreg()` - for it to be called, your `modelA` object must be of `survreg` class, i.e. it should be created using `survreg()` call instead of `coxph()` call.